# How to rotate and translate using CSS in IE8?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

We've added some new fancy css to our page that uses transform rules, however we need to keep compatibility with IE8 and those rules don't work there. All we did was rotate and translate a few elements and I managed to do the rotation in IE8 using this code:

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(SizingMethod='auto expand', M11=0.7071067811865476, M12=0.7071067811865475, M21=-0.7071067811865475, M22=0.7071067811865476)";
```

However I have no clue how to do the translation part. I tried to add third column to the matrix and see if it'll work, but no translation was happening. I tried both with and without px, but the result was the same. I also tried to adding a third row (0,0,1), but that didn't work either.

I know there are workaround libraries for this, but it would honestly be overkill. I just need to add IE8 specific translation to what I already have.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=translate

Comment: There's no shame in relying on graceful degredation for ancient browsers. Do you have so many IE8 users that your whizbang is important for them?

Comment: @isherwood There are not that many people using IE8 per see, but they still buy our stuff, so it's not the best idea to make the page look bad\unusable for them. We already dropped support for IE7, because it was impossible to make our page compatible with it (and almost no one used it anyway), however IE8 and IE9 are still too widely used by our users, so we need to support those browsers a little longer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't figured out how (or if I can) do the translation alongside the rotation using `-ms-filter`, but I managed to achieve my goal using good old margin.

At first I thought that I can simply use the `\9` hack to target IE8, but unfortunately it not only affects IE8 and below, but also IE9 and IE 10.

During tests I also discovered that `-ms-filter` is messing with IE9, so in the end I added the IE8 specific css using conditional comments:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<style>
    .something{
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(SizingMethod='auto expand', M11=0.7071067811865476, M12=0.7071067811865475, M21=-0.7071067811865475, M22=0.7071067811865476)";
        margin-left:-40px
        margin-top:-40px
    }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```